# What should I use for presentations on Linux?

Tags: linux, presentations

I was looking for a descent powerpoint presentation software for Linux. 
I am seriously not bugged up with openoffice presentation tool. I am not looking for Microsoft Office or Apples's iWork.

Is there a better option for Linux?

Comment: What's your programming question?

Answer (score 5):

Did you try Beamer? It provides very clean slides using LateX, very professional!

Comment: The URL is http://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/wiki/Home and here a guide: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/en/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations

Answer (score 0):

You can try a cloud-based one, like Google Docs, I think it outputs files in several different formats.

Answer (score 0):

The best compatibility from Linux probably stems from Softmaker. Their software isn't very cheap under Linuxer standards, but the sofware is sound.

Another option, if you have a copy of Office that is wine-compatible (i.e. Office 2000 or 2007) and don't mind losing clipart, is to install Office on Wine. The Office EULA permits 2 installation given that they are on the owner's computer, for use by the owner, and that they aren't both used at the same time (i.e. you can't have the other copy open while using one copy). Instructions to make the programs work better can be found on appdb.winehq.org.

Lastly, you can use an Office installation (or a Windows computer) to export your file into a .pdf file, which you can use with evince in slideshow move (open the file and hit F5).